# Using PINRemoteImage to populate CollectionViewCell Images

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I make a network call in `ViewDidLoad` to get objects (first 25), then I make another call in `willDisplayCell` to get the rest of the objects.  I'm Using `PINReMoteImage` in the code below.  It works, but the problem is that as you scroll through the collection view, a cell will have one picture then another picture will appear over it.  How can I improve this UI?  I thought `updateWithProgress` was supposed to deal with this by using a blur until the image is loaded but it doesn't seem to be working?

```
  override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {



        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PinCollectionViewCell


        if let pinImageURL = self.pins[indexPath.row].largestImage().url {

            cell.pinImage?.pin_updateWithProgress = true
            cell.pinImage?.pin_setImageFromURL(pinImageURL, completion: ({ (result : PINRemoteImageManagerResult) -> Void in

                if let image = result.image {
                    self.imageArray.append(image)
                }

            }))


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I'm reusing cells, but I wasn't resetting the image.  So I simply added `cell.pinImage?.image = nil` to the above.  Once I found out that was the problem I added an `UIActivityViewIndicatorView`to the cell and stop it when the image comes in.